# Log in to Sharpoint using Kerberos (c#)

Tags: c#, authentication, sharepoint, kerberos

This is the first time I'm exploring Kerberos.
My final goal is to be able to log in to Sharepoint using Kerberos.

For example, having a form with a button, and when I press it I get access to sharepoint using KERBEROS.

I spent almost a week searching for code samples or any related information and I'm still confused.

Is the "log in to Sharepoint using Kerberos" is just configurations or does it require writing code?

That link suggest it's all about configurations:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg502602(v=office.14).aspx

Here it seems to be mixed, tho not sure it has something to do with sarepoint:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27554/Authentication-in-web-services-using-C-and-Kerbero
http://www.example-code.com/csharp/http_kerberos.asp

I also downloaded microsoft SSPI code sample which was very very complex and didn't work.

So even after a week I'm still clueless of how to do it, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your SharePoint instance is configured with Kerberos correctly, it should be a snap.

1. Create a new instance of a default HTTP client in C#.
2. Set the credential to DefaultNetworkCredential.
3. Call the URL
4. Consume the response

The HTTP client will, by default obtain a service ticket for the HTTP server with your TGT. The second point is the most important one.

Comment: The DefaultNetworkCredential is going to be one of the NT AUTHORITY "users" unless the Application Pool's identity in IIS is set with a specific user in mind.